# Merging a Shapefile and a dataframe

Tags: r, merge, shapefile, r-mapview

I am working  in `R` with a regular dataframe (`df`) and a shapefile (`map2`), the share a common column called `CD116FP`. `df` has 103552 lines while `map2` has 444 .I am loading the shapefile in the following way:

> map2 <- read_sf("D:/Data/tl_2019_us_cd116.shp")

My end-goal is to use the function `mapview()` to view the map included in `map2` with the "intensity" that is described in `df` under the column `np_scores`. I hence do not want observations of `df` that do not appear on `map2`.

Here are my thoughts and failures:

1. If these two objects were regular dataframes, a reasonable candidate would be to use `merge()` to combine both objects, however if you apply that function in this case, the resulting object looses the spatial properties and `mapview` does not know how to read it.
2. Another approach that I used was trying this line of code:

> map2m<-data.frame(map2, df[match(map2$CD116FP, df$CD116FP),])

But the result has dimensions that are too big (much bigger that 444 lines) and hence `mapview` crashes when trying to plot the desired map.

3. At last, I went full-on brute force and just constructed a loop to add the column `np` to `map2`:

```
map2$np=10

for (i in c(1:nrow(map2)))
{  
for (j in c(1:nrow(df)))
 {
if (identical(map2$CD116FP[i],df$CD116FP[j]))
{map2$np[i]=df$np_score[j]}
else {map2$np[i]=0}  
}
}
```

However, this approach just takes way too much time given the dimensions of my dataframe.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the .shp? Or perhaps share a similar file?

Comment: Sure! It is here: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/CD/tl_2019_us_cd116.zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled by the structure of your data. Your `df` has over 100,000 rows, so I'm guessing that the same `CD116FP` occurs multiple times in `df`, and the `npscore` will presumably vary across these instances. If you want to merge these to `map2` you will need to aggregate them first.

Let's try to recreate a similar setup:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1

map2 <- read_sf("C:/users/administrator/documents/shape/tl_2019_us_cd116.shp")

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(CD116FP = sprintf("%02d", sample(0:99, 103552, TRUE)),
                 npscores = runif(103552))

head(df)
#>   CD116FP  npscores
#> 1      95 0.6927742
#> 2      80 0.8543845
#> 3      90 0.5220353
#> 4      01 0.1449647
#> 5      76 0.9876543
#> 6      38 0.5629950
```

I have made `df` have the same number of rows that your data has to show this solution will scale to your problem.

Let's aggregate the `npscores` with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df_sum <- df %>% 
  filter(CD116FP %in% map2$CD116FP) %>%
  group_by(CD116FP) %>%
  summarise(npscores = mean(npscores))

map2$npscores <- df_sum$npscores[match(map2$CD116FP, df_sum$CD116FP)]
```

Now `map2` has the aggregated `npscores` we can plot - for example, in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(map2) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = npscores)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-180, -60),
            ylim = c(15, 70)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "gold")
```

[image]

Or in mapview:

```r
library(mapview)
mapView(map2, zcol = "npscores")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! the proper user of dplyr was what I needed. An extra question, how do you deal with possible NAs in the npsocres when ploting in ggplot?

Comment: Actually, it seems to not be a problem of the NAs. I am getting the correct plot with mapView, but with ggplot I get the following message: "Regions defined for each Polygons
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'np_score' not found"

Comment: I was using `npscores` in my code - just check the names are consistent @WeierstraßRamirez

Comment: Yeah I had noticed. I adapted it in my code accordingly but is get that same error.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez you would only get that error if your plot code contains a variable called `np_score`. Where is that coming from? What are the column names in `map2`?

Comment: I changed npscores in your to np_score when i passed it to mine for compatibility

Answer (score 2):

I've had some luck using plain old [`merge`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/merge) from the base package. Here's an excerpt from my own work should this be valuable to you :-)

```
my_data <- read_excel("TraderDataRaw.xlsx", 
      sheet = "fsa", 
      col_types= c("text","text","text","logical","numeric","numeric")) %>% 
      mutate(resp_rate=mailed/responses)

my_map <- st_read("lfsa000b16a_e.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

my_merged_data <- merge(my_map, my_data, 
      by.x=c("CFSAUID","PRUID","PRNAME"), 
      by.y=c("CFSAUID","PRUID","PRNAME"))
```