# Merging Information into a Shapefile

Tags: r, leaflet, mapping, data-visualization, geo

I have a shapefile ("my_shapefile") in R.

**Part 1:** If I try inspecting this shapefile and check its contents by adding a "$" - there appears to be 3 parts:

```
head(my_shapefile$var1)
H1C Y8L K9H B6U
200 Levels: H1C Y8L K9H B6U ....

head(my_shapefile$var2)
[1] 55 75 65 45 
Levels: 15 20 25 30...

head(my_shapefile$var3)
[1] zone1 zone2 zone3
10 Levels: zone1 zone2 zone 3...
```

**Part 2:** When I inspect this shapefile using the "str" command, I get the following output:

```
    str(my_shapefile)
    
  .. ..$ : Formal Class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots:
.. .. .. ..@Polygons: List of 1
.. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal Class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
.. .. .. .. ..@labpt  : num[1:2] -64.4 44.3
.. .. .. .. ..@area   : num 0.00045
.. .. .. .. ..@hole   : logi FALSE
.. .. .. .. ..@ringDir : int 1
.. .. .. .. ..@coords : num[1:567, 1:2] -65.5, -65.5, -65.5, -65.5, 

.. .. .. .. ..@plotOrder: int 1
.. .. .. .. ..@ labpt: num[1:2] -64.4 44.3
.. .. .. .. ..@ ID: chr "98"
.. .. .. .. ..@ area: num 0.0045
```

**Part 3:** When I inspect this shapefile using "@", I get the following (sample) outputs:

```
my_shapefile@polygons


[[711]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] -54.1881  49.5854

Slot "area":
[1] 4.845081e-05

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
            [,1]     [,2]
  [1,] -54.18229 49.58693
  [2,] -54.18233 49.58670
  [3,] -54.18218 49.58659

my_shapefile@plotOrder
 [1] 15 25 15 25
```

I have an aggregate dataset ("ag_data") that looks something like this (ag_data$var has the same levels as my_shapefile$var1):

```
head(ag_data)
  var count
1 H1C    15
2 Y8L    17
3 K9H    99
4 B6U    12
```

**Is it possible to somehow "merge" this "ag_data" with "my_shapefile"?**

I already created a "leaflet" map ("my_map") using some pre-existing data ("old_data") and the shapefile:

```
    library(leaflet)
# first make basic map
my_map = old_data %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())

# next, add shapefile to the basic map
my_map %>% addPolygons(data = my_shapefile, weight = 5, col = 'blue')
```

Based on the "count" variable from "ag_data", I would like to modify the map to create a "choropleth"/heatmap with the following type of legend (where the "color/shading" is proportional to ag_data$count ):

[image]

I found this older post ([Merging a Shapefile and a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942746/merging-a-shapefile-and-a-dataframe)) in which a similar topic is discussed, but I am not sure if this is relevant.

- Can someone please show me how I can merge the aggregate data to the shapefile, and then create this map/legend (where color/shading is proportional to ag_data$count) ?

Thank you!

Comment: You have read your shape file as an `sp` object. To make your life easier I would suggest to read it as an `sf` object using `sf::st_read` or convert `my_shapefile` to an sf object using `sf::st_as_sf`. An `sf` object behaves and looks more or less like a normal dataframe. After doing so you should be able to easily merge your aggregated data to the shape file by the regional identifier as outlined in the post you referenced.

Comment: @ stefan: thank you for this suggestion! I now used the following command to import the shapefile

Comment: shape_file<- sf::st_read("C:/Users/me/Documents/shape_folder/shape_file.shp", options = "ENCODING=WINDOWS-1252")

Comment: I will now start looking how to proceed from here!